# Interface generic parent child object initialization

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a interface with constraint as a Base class

```
abstract class BaseElement { };
interface IOperation <T>where T:BaseElement
{
    void Add (T field1);

}
```

Created a child object for the Base class

```
class StudentDTO : BaseElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
};

class SubjectDTO : BaseElement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
};
```

Implemented 2 classes with IOperation interface

```
class Student : IOperation<StudentDTO>
{
    public void Add(StudentDTO field1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child A" + field1.Id);
    }
}

class Subject : IOperation<SubjectDTO>
{     

    public void Add(SubjectDTO field1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child B" + field1.Name);
    }
}
```

Implemented a factory pattern to return the DTO objects.

```
static class BLFactory
{
    public static IOperation<BaseElement> CreateObject(BaseElement baseObject)
    {
        if (baseObject.GetType().Name == "SubjectDTO")
        {
            return new StudentDTO() as IOperation<BaseElement>;
        }
        else
        {
            var temp = new SubjectDTO() as IOperation<BaseElement>;
            return temp;
            ////************ temp object returns null *************
        }
    }        
}
```

Now, when I use the BLFactory to create the DTO objects, I am getting it as NULL. Not sure how to fix the problem.
Any advice how to fix this or what is the right way of implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off `StudentDTO` doesn't implement `IOperation` at all; `Student` does, but `StudentDTO` doesn't.

And even if you *did* use `Student` that wouldn't work either.  Student implements `IOperation<StudentDTO>` not `IOperation<BaseElement>`.

Just because `StudentDTO` can be implicitly converted to `BaseElement` does *not* mean that `IOperation<StudentDTO>` can be implicitly converted to `IOperation<BaseElement>`.  `IOperation` would need to be covariant for that to be the case, and it's not.

If you wanted, you could make `IOperation` *contravariant*, given that `T` is only used as input, but that would then enable you to implicitly convert an `IOperation<BaseElement>` to an `IOperation<StudentDTO>`, not the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Because `SubjectDTO` is NOT an `IOperation<BaseElement>`.  It is a `BaseElement`.

Neither is a `Subject` - it is an `IOperation<SubjectDTO>` which does NOT inherit from `IOperation<BaseElement>`.

It seems like your `BLFactory` is basically returning the proper "repository" for each type, which may be better done declaratively using a DI framework like Ninject or Unity.

However, if you want to hard-code it, you *could* make `BLFactory` generic:

```
static class BLFactory<U> where U:BaseElement
{
    public static IOperation<U> CreateObject()
    {
        if (typeof(U).Name == "SubjectDTO")
        {
            return new Student() as IOperation<U>;
        }
        else
        {
            return new Subject() as IOperation<U>;
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) of `as` operator:

> The **as** operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, **as** returns `null` instead of raising an exception.

As `StudentDTO` is not inherited from `IOperation<...>` and `SubjectDTO` is not inherited from `IOperation<...>` you will get `null` in `temp` variable as result of `as` operatior.